# How to remove character from string?

Tags: c#

I have a string which is getting from a userInput. What I want to do now is removing a unique character from this string but only remove it once. The main problem is that this unique character doesn't have a unique index. For example:
User has input a string like : "0123456", and now I want to remove the first '1',so the string will be output like "023456". How ever, if a user input a string like "01123456", how can I remove the first '1' and make it looks like "0123456"? I am looking for a method that can be used for both of situation. I was using string.TrimStart(), but doesn't get what I want. How can I do this?

Comment: `IndexOf('1')` returns the index of the first `1`; then use `Substring`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Stack is not a code-service.

Comment: Hi @HimBromBeere, I know my question description is a little bit long. But If you read it carefully, I already said I tried TrimStart(). More that, I tried  Remove(), SubString(). Neither of them can get what I want. I think I will following the answers and have a try. But thank you let me know Stack is not a code-service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Remove` and `IndexOf`.

```
var str = "01123456";
var i = str.IndexOf('1'); // IndexOf returns -1 when there is no element found, so we need to handle that when calling remove.
var res = (i >= 0) ? str.Remove(i, 1) : str;
Console.WriteLine(res); // 0123456
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you what you need is `string.Remove` method. See MSDN documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Remove_System_Int32_System_Int32_

If you don't know where is your character, at first call `string.IndexOf` to find it. If this call returns nonnegaive number, call `Remove` to remove it. Just note that string is immutable so it will always create a new object.

Answer (score 0):

```
yourstring = yourstring.IndexOf('1') != -1 ? yourstring.Remove(yourstring.IndexOf('1'), 1) : yourstring;
```

Comment: What is RemoveAt it doesn't exist does it?

Comment: And what if the string you are searching for doesn't exist? You will get an error as indexof will return -1

Comment: Well, if you want to remove a '1' from a string with a '1', that's how you do it. If you want to remove any character from a string and have error checking, then try catch it, I suppose

Comment: How about that? Single line, no extra variables, etc etc

Comment: I don't believe you need to create 2 variables every time you need to remove a character from a string

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use a combination of [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2), [`Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=netframework-4.7.2), and [`IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
if (userInput.Contains('1')) userInput = userInput.Remove(userInput.IndexOf('1'), 1);
```

Or if you want to be Linq-y...

```
userInput = string.Concat(userInput.TakeWhile(chr => chr != '1')
    .Concat(userInput.SkipWhile(chr => chr != '1').Skip(1)));
```